# Should the amazon S3 bucket region be closer to the host server or the client server?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage, web-storage

I have a website hosted on heroku which is US based, but my target audience is in India. I just have to display images from the storage to the users.
For faster loading of the images, should the storage region be US or should it be India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the images stored in the buckets in the region closest to your targetr audience would be better.

However, for even **faster response** times for your images, you could have a look at using [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) to cache your images in AWS **edge locations** closest to your users.

If this is something of interest to you, you can read more about the use of CloudFront and S3 in the **AWS blog post**:

- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/).